# Undefined variable in Microsoft documentation example regarding SignalR Core Authentication

Tags: authentication, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr

I've got an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API which uses SignalR Core.
I'm following the Microsoft documentation regarding SignalR authentication, but I'm struggling with a certain section. If you look at their sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2

They have a section I need help with:

```
        // Configure JWT Bearer Auth to expect our security key
        options.TokenValidationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, param) =>
                {
                    return expires > DateTime.UtcNow;
                },
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateActor = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKey
            };
```

What is SecurityKey? It's not defined anywhere.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the source code [Startup](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/signalr/authn-and-authz/sample/Startup.cs#L23), and will find the defination for `SecurityKey`.

```
public static readonly SymmetricSecurityKey SecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
```

Comment: Thanks Tao. So it looks like in that example, they are using a random GUID. But in my live application, should I be getting the security key from somewhere? Perhaps from my authentication server? (Auth0)

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez In general, there is no need, but it depends on you. The `SecurityKey` is just used to sign during encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Thanks Tao. I will implement that and see if it works